# Solve this equation (function)

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, systems-of-equations

my name is Agapita and I am studying for a test tomorrow. I would really appreciate your help with this exercise.

---

It says:

> Solve the equation $2\arccos(x^2-4)\geq \pi$

I have the solutions but I do not really know how to get there. The solution is:

$\left[-2,-\sqrt3\right]\cup\left[\sqrt3,2\right]$

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Do you mean the equation $$2\arccos(x^2-4)\geq\pi$$??

Comment: yeah, precisely

Comment: you need to know that $\arccos z > \frac {\pi}{2}$ when $z<0$  and $\arccos z$ is undefined when $z< -1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that $\cos^{-1}:[-1,1] \to [0,\pi]$, You have $$2\arccos(x^2-4)\geq \pi \iff \arccos(x^2-4)\geq \frac{\pi}{2}.$$ Since $\cos:[0,\pi] \to [-1,1]$ is strictly decreasing then $$x^2-4 \leq \cos \frac{\pi}{2}=0.$$ The solution to this inequality is $S_1=[-2,2]$.

But you have to keep in mind that the domain of $\arccos$ is $[-1,1]$, so you need to find the solution of $$-1\leq x^2-4\leq 1 \iff 3\leq x^2 \leq 5,$$ which is $S_2=[-\sqrt{5}, -\sqrt{3}] \cup [\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}]$.

Finally, the solution to your inequality is $$S_1 \cap S_2= [-2,-\sqrt{3}] \cup [\sqrt{3}, 2].$$

Comment: @Agapita You’re welcome. Also, notice that what you are trying to solve is an inequality, not an equation. :)

Comment: right, right. By the way, i don't understand one thing..How do you get the cos: [0, π] ? How do you know that?

Comment: @Agapita $\arccos$ is the inverse function of $\cos$, hence $\cos$ has to be bijective. Since $\cos$ y a  *circular function* is not inyective in $\mathbb{R}$, that's why you need to restrict the domain. In $[0,\pi]$ $\cos$ is injective (you can also choose $[\pi, 2\pi]$, $[-5\pi,-4\pi]$, $[-\pi,0]$, etc... in general you can choose any interval of the form $[k\pi, (k+1)\pi]$, with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$), but is a convention to choose $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: A similar case ocurrs with $\arcsin$, you choose the domain  $\left[ \frac{-\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$(by convention, even though any interval of the form $\left[ \frac{k\pi}{2}, \frac{(k+1)\pi}{2} \right]$ works).